# addSubview breaking internal contraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I'm having some trouble with dynamically adding subviews to each other. Namely, when I have a view with constraints built in the interface builder and then use `[view addSubview:subview]`, it destroys all of the constraints that I have set up.

I've tried adding `[subview setAutoresizingMask:NO];` as well as `subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;`

I expected that the subview's constraints to its original parent would be broken, and added them back in programmatically after my call to `addSubview`, but I didn't expect that the constraints of its children would also be broken.

Unfortunately, adding back in child constraints is not feasible. The architecture we're using is a plugin model, and while it's simple enough to resize the plugin's container from the main `UIViewController`, the plugin needs to be responsible for positioning its internal elements.

Here's a mock up of how things should look:
[image: How it should look]

And here's what it currently looks like:
[image: How it actually looks]

How can I get `addSubview` to maintain those internal constraints? The red, green, and blue boxes are only constrained to each other and their parent (purple), which are all brought through with `addSubview`.

Comment: When you add View1 as a subview, how are you defining its size and position? Are you using constraints? If so, what constraints are you adding?

Comment: Its width, leading, and top are tied to its new parent (equal width, 0 for the others). The height is static.

Comment: The internal constraints shouldn't be lost (they aren't when I try it). You should be setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false, so that's fine. I think you're going to have to be more explicit about what constraints you have, so show the whole code for how you load and add this view, as well as the constraints you add.

Answer (score 0):

I tried too many ways includes sizeToFit()and setting the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints but it did not work. You should set width of the custom view which you want to add as subview and you should set the view's sizeToFit(). it worked for me:

```
bigView.sizeToFit()
subView.sizeToFit()
subView.width = screenWidth
bigView.addSubview(subView)
```